# Import Error: No module named Quirks while trying to install nvidia-390

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, python

There was a problem with my Nvidia drivers, so I had to delete them all (with purge). But now, when I'm trying to reinstall nvidia-390, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 26 in <module>
  import Quirks.quirkapplier
ImportError: No module named 'Quirks'
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-390 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
...
```

This is not a surprise as I can't find a folder named Quirks in "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, and I don't know how to install it manually, as all simple commands that pass through my mind, such as pip install python3-quirks,... don't work.

Comment: I think you need to install `ubuntu-drivers-common`. The first Google search for `Quirks.quirkapplier` points to a [Github project](https://github.com/tseliot/ubuntu-drivers-common) by that name, and there is a package `ubuntu-drivers-common` in the repos.

Comment: @Jos I can't also install ubuntu-drivers-common for the same reason

Comment: You must have accidentally uninstalled too much - `ubuntu-drivers-common` is a dependency of `ubuntu-desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common
```

This fixed missing `Quirks.quirkapplier` when installing `nvidia-410`.

Answer (score 0):

In `ubuntu 16.04`, if you manually updated the latest version of `python3` that is not supported by the ubuntu version, this error may occur even though `ubuntu-drivers-common` is already installed.

In this case, you can either revert the `python3` link to the previous version, or change the `python3` executable specified in `/usr/bin/quirks-handler` to the previous version executable(ex: `python3.5`).